# Incrementing multi-column sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequences, multiple-columns

Is there any built-in way (I mean, without need of triggers and/or functions) to have incrementing indexes per multiple columns?

So after performing:

```
INSERT INTO "table"
    ("month", "desc")
    VALUES
    (1, 'One thing')
,   (1, 'Another thing')
,   (1, 'Last task of the month')
,   (2, 'Last task of the month')
,   (2, 'Last task of the month')
,   (3, 'First of third month')
```

My table would end up like this (note the "task" column):

```
month    task    desc
1        1       One thing
1        2       Another thing
1        3       Last task of the month
2        1       First of second month
2        2       Second and last of second month
3        1       First of third month
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add simlpe `SERIAL` column to your table (it will give you the order for things) and then use something like:

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY serial_column)
FROM table
```

This will give you the results you want.

If you do not need to order the rows, you can try:

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY month)
FROM table
```

Details here : [`row_number() OVER(...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

UPD How it works:

A column with type `SERIAL` is essentially an "auto increment" field. It automatically get a value from a sequence. When you insert rows to the table they will look like this:

```
| MONTH | SERIAL_COLUMN |                     DESCRIPTION |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|     1 |             1 |                       One thing |
|     1 |             2 |                   Another thing |
|     1 |             3 |          Last task of the month |
|     2 |             4 |           First of second month |
|     2 |             5 | Second and last of second month |
|     3 |             6 |            First of third month |
```

The key thing - every next added row has value of `SERIAL_COLUMN` **greater** than all previous rows.

Next. The `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY serial_column)` does:

1) Partition all the rows into groups with equal `month` (`PARTITION BY month`)

2) Orders them by value of `serial_column` (`ORDER BY serial_column`)

3) In every group assigns a row number using the ordering from step 2 (`` `row_number() OVER ``)

The output is:

```
| MONTH | SERIAL_COLUMN |                     DESCRIPTION | ROW_NUMBER |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1 |             1 |                       One thing |          1 |
|     1 |             2 |                   Another thing |          2 |
|     1 |             3 |          Last task of the month |          3 |
|     2 |             4 |           First of second month |          1 |
|     2 |             5 | Second and last of second month |          2 |
|     3 |             6 |            First of third month |          1 |
```

To change the output of the `row_number()` you need to change the values in `SERIAL_COLUMN`. Fro example, to place `Second and last of second month` before `First of second month` a will change the values of `SERIAL_COLUMN` like that:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET serial_column = 5
WHERE description = 'First of second month';

UPDATE Table1
SET serial_column = 4
WHERE description = 'Second and last of second month';
```

It will change the output of the query:

```
| MONTH | SERIAL_COLUMN |                     DESCRIPTION | ROW_NUMBER |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1 |             1 |                       One thing |          1 |
|     1 |             2 |                   Another thing |          2 |
|     1 |             3 |          Last task of the month |          3 |
|     2 |             4 | Second and last of second month |          1 |
|     2 |             5 |           First of second month |          2 |
|     3 |             6 |            First of third month |          1 |
```

The exact values in `SERIAL_COLUMN` do not matter. **They only set an order on the tasks in a month.**

My SQLFiddle example is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/af875/3).

Comment: This is the way to do it. In a multi-user environment it is *very hard* to enforce gapless numbering without creating **race conditions**. You would have to use table locks heavily, which is a real downer for performance. I suggest you use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`. Result is the same in the absence of peers (like in this case), but `row_number()` is the cheaper and more appropriate function.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for `row_number()`. I edited the queries.

Comment: Can I later change the order of the tasks inside a month?

Comment: @Alec Yes. You will need to change the value in the `serial_column`.

Comment: I am a little lost, which will be the serial_column? The month or the task?

Comment: @Alec If you want to define an order on the tasks in the month - you need additional column in the table itself. In my example I added column with name `serial_column` and type `SERIAL`(= auto increment).

Comment: @Alec Wait a minute. I will add an explanation.

Comment: @Alec Added detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks Igor, now it makes perfect sense and I actually find it a really neat solution.

Comment: Hey there, is there a way to group the month and the row_number to a unique contraint? i want to have something like a version of a document which should have the version and the name of the document as a unique contraint and the version should just be a number that gets raised by 1 everytime the document gets updated

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to break your `INSERT` statements into one row of data per insert, then you could use [PostgreSQL rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/rules-update.html). The example that follows is a bit convoluted in that rules don't seem to let you redirect writes to a relation itself. That's usually done with triggers. But we're seeing if this is possible without triggers, so here goes:

```
--drop table table_data cascade;
CREATE TABLE table_data (
  month integer not null,
  task integer not null,
  "desc" text
);
ALTER TABLE table_data add primary key (month, task);

CREATE VIEW "table" as 
 select month, task, "desc" from table_data;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE calculate_task AS ON INSERT TO "table"
  DO INSTEAD
  INSERT into table_data (month, task, "desc") 
  VALUES (
  NEW.month, 
  (select coalesce(max(task),0) + 1 from table_data where month = NEW.month), 
  NEW."desc");

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "table" ("month", "desc") VALUES (1, 'One thing');
INSERT INTO "table" ("month", "desc") VALUES (1, 'Another thing');
INSERT INTO "table" ("month", "desc") VALUES (1, 'Last task of the month');
INSERT INTO "table" ("month", "desc") VALUES (2, 'Last task of the month');
INSERT INTO "table" ("month", "desc") VALUES (2, 'Last task of the month');
INSERT INTO "table" ("month", "desc") VALUES (3, 'First of third month');
COMMIT;

select * from "table";
```

*Notes*

- If you need to support DELETE/UPDATE on "table", then you could add rules for each those actions as well.
- The `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` block above is used to show that even within the same transaction, this method will work as long as each row is broken into its own `INSERT`.
- You use a few [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `table` and `desc`. Be sure to double-quote them as you've done and you won't have any problems.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/98e10/2) is the above code in sqlfiddle